# How to tell if an Expedition site is "claimed"?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

Basically, **How close is too close?**

Other civs regularly get annoyed if you dig up one of *"their"* dig sites, and will demand that you stop doing it.

Since the game doesn't tell you that you have broken a promise until after you do so, I want to try and find out how to tell if they will have claimed a dig site before I dig.

I assume any Expedition site within 3 squares of one of their cities is going to count even if the city border hasn't expanded out to it, but does anyone know how much further out their claims extend?

Comment: As an addendum, this mechanic is so frustrating to predict! I found some ruins which where halfway between my civ's borders and another civ's (but 1 hex closer to them). So I refrained from excavating them because I had promised not to take "their" ruins, and assumed they were claiming it. Then I built a new city right near the ruins, making the ruins just outside my border, clearly "my" ruins now right? I figured I was allowed to do an expedition. Nope, civ got angry at me.

Comment: Expansion also causes similar problems. I had it where I expanded on my continent with another city and the highest scoring AI told me I was settling in his land. I think it depends on the AI's power to how much land around them they regard as theirs. I have had the same thing with an expedition site where a site on the tip of my continent was considered theirs. This was approx 10 tiles away across water. So I reckon it is a calculation of both distance and the difference between the AI's and your score/military power.

Comment: I'm really bad at keeping my promises to the other civs.  I always tell them "ok I'll stop" to appease them... but then I up and do it anyway because I NEED MORE THINGS.  And they don't.  That's fair right?  :D

Comment: It could also be that it dependend on were their explorer is. Lets say a ruin is not really close to their city but there is an explorer or other toops in the vicinity and you take the ruin, they might get angry

Comment: I wonder if this has something to do with when an AI has an explorer en route to the site. The game would know that it is their intention to move the unit there and then perform the action on the site, the AI may consider it claimed at this point no matter the distance.

Comment: @nzifnab Welcome to geo-political politics. Just don't complain when you get invaded IRL by someone who needs more things.

Comment: Maybe it depends on whose unit first discovered the site? Although I have no idea how to test that theory :/

Answer (score 1):

I always assume that if the explorer can see the city border from the expedition site you are too close.

Comment: While true, a civ could also consider a site further than that to be "theirs".

Comment: Got any evidence or testing to back that up?

Comment: @Ellesedil: In Civ V, different civilizations (I assume their underlying personality) consider different ranges their property. IIRC that depended on a good number of reasons, e.g. your and their military strength when discussing settling cities too close. I can only assume a similar approach is taken in BE.